# Is this line from The Merchant of Venice metaphorical?

Tags: literature, shakespeare, literary-device

From "The Merchant of Venice", Act IV:

> The quality of mercy is not strain'd,
>   It droppeth as the gentle rain from heaven

Can we consider that a metaphor?

Comment: Why do you think you could or could not consider it a metaphor?

Comment: Also, look up the definition of *simile*.

Comment: Yes; are similes metaphors? Or are they only **similar** to metaphors? What else can be strained, besides honey, muscles, tempers, coffee, and attitudes?

Comment: Ah, that old philosophical question -- is a simile like a metaphor, or is a metaphor like a simile?

Comment: Of **course** it's a metaphor. Similes, metonymies, and metaphors are all the same kind of thing -- talking about one thing as if it were another thing. They all behave the same way, and the only difference between _My love is a red, red, rose_ and _My love is like a red, red, rose_ is one syllable. If you're interested in identifying metaphors, take a look at [Lakoff and Johnson's _Metaphors We Live By_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question – "Is it metaphorical?" – *definitely*.  It describes mercy using the image of rain falling from the sky.

In true Shakespearean fashion, this line is doubly metaphorical and ***profound*** in the choice of metaphor, suggesting that mercy itself originates from heaven (i.e. God-given), as evidenced in the rest of the passage:

> The quality of mercy is not strained.
>   It droppeth as the gentle rain from heaven
>   Upon the place beneath. It is twice blessed:
>   It blesseth him that gives and him that takes.
>   'Tis mightiest in the mightiest. It becomes
>   The thronèd monarch better than his crown.
>   His scepter shows the force of temporal power,
>   The attribute to awe and majesty
>   Wherein doth sit the dread and fear of kings,
>   But mercy is above this sceptered sway.
>   It is enthronèd in the hearts of kings.
>   **It is an attribute to God himself**.

Answer (score -1):

Metaphors don't contain words such as "as" or "like" typical of comparisons. Metaphors are genuine substitutions of a common word by another expression based on 
comparison. If you say "black gold" you substitue the word oil or petroleum with another expression. You compare oil to gold and use "black" to indicate that you don't really mean gold and that you use a metaphor.

Answer (score -1):

It is a simile (note the word "as").

Comment: While I agree, this doens't explain to the question asker why you a right.